# Why have the "jquery." prefix on plugin filenames?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, naming-conventions

I'm curious as to the reasoning behind the standard procedure of prefixing jQuery plugin filenames with "jquery.". Several tutorials state something like:

> The use of the "**jquery.**" prefix eliminates any possible name collisions with files intended for use with other libraries.

I believe I have even seen a couple of plugins that actually require themselves not be renamed.

Are there any more specific reasons for this prefix, or is it simple the convention?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's just a convention, for example:

```
jquery.lightbox.js
prototype.lightbox.js
```

If you just had this and were using both, well, you see where confusion sets in:

```
lightbox.js
```

Also, you might be using just vanilla JavaScript function files, and not want those to have a prefix, e.g. `editor.js`, denoting it has no reliance on jQuery at all...it's all around organization and maintainability.

Comment: One could also throw everything in a `jquery` directory to get the same effect, but I suppose that would then require breaking up a possible package that has `example.js`, `jquery.example.js`, `prototype.example.js`, and `example.css` together.

Comment: @Mike - That's certainly a valid approach as well...there are probably a dozen valid approached here, the `jquery.` is just the most common...whichever method works for you, use it :)